# Select rows until a total amount is met in a column (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have seen this issue in SF, but me being a noob I just can't get my fried brain around them. So please forgive me if this feels like repetition.

My Sample Table

```
--------------------------
ID   | Supplier   | QTY
--------------------------
1       1          2
2       1          2
3       2          5
4       3          2
5       1          3
6       2          4
```

I need to get the rows "UNTIL" the cumulative total for "QTY" is equal or greater than 5 in descending order for a particular supplier id.

In this example, for supplier 1, it will be rows with the ids of 5 and 2.

```
    Id - unique primary key
    Supplier - foreign key, there is another table for supplier info.
    Qty - double
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Using two variables.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d57a/27)

Query:

```
set @tot:=0;
set @sup:=0;

select x.id, x.supplier, x.ctot
from (
select id, supplier, qty,
@tot:= (case when @sup = supplier then
@tot + qty else qty end) as ctot,
@sup:=supplier
from demo
order by supplier asc, id desc) x
where x.ctot >=5
;

| ID | SUPPLIER | CTOT |
------------------------
|  2 |        1 |    5 |
|  1 |        1 |    7 |
|  3 |        2 |    5 |
```

Comment: @ElaBuwa take a look at thsi and comment, the `order by id desc` is not very clear in terms of matching to `cumulative total >=5`

Comment: Hi B, thank you for taking the trouble to set an sqlfiddle. I needed it to be in DESC format since this something of a stock/inventory related table. Will this work, if I needed to get the rows for 1 supplier? The whole "@" thing is a bit new, doing some googling on it now. :D. Once again, thank you very much. Will definitely check it and update the thread

Comment: If you want to get up to `5` cumulative total then it could track the relevant `id`s that made it up. Otherwise hmm... BTW every word that is starting with `@` is a variable :)

Comment: @ElaBuwa it seems you will need to get `<=5` means up to 5 the `ID` descending order, then `ID 5, 2` is picked up for `supplier 1`, player around a bit and comment please. BTW every word that is starting with `@` is a `variable` :) Then you can filter out any supplier who does't have a `max total of 5`

Comment: is there possible to get total sum qty 5 crossed records and max values records of not crossed total sum qty suppliers record like i mentioned in this scresnshot?
https://nimb.ws/FVSyeW

Comment: @user3157334 do you mind sharing the your sqlfiddle? I do not follow your what you meant by "crossed records".. Do you mind renaming your fields and write what your raw data is and what result you expect in plain text and numbers.?

Answer (score 3):

It ain't pretty, but I think this does it and maybe it can be the basis of something less cumbersome.  Note that I use a "fake" INNER JOIN just to get some variable initialized for the first time--it serves no other role.

```
SELECT ID,
       supplier,
       qty,
       cumulative_qty
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        supplier,
        qty,
        -- next line keeps a running total quantity by supplier id
        @cumulative_quantity := if (@sup <> supplier, qty, @cumulative_quantity + qty) as cumulative_qty,
        -- next is 0 for running total < 5 by supplier, 1 the first time >= 5, and ++ after
        @reached_five := if (@cumulative_quantity < 5, 0, if (@sup <> supplier, 1, @reached_five + 1)) as reached_five,
        -- next takes note of changes in supplier being processed
        @sup := if(@sup <> supplier, supplier, @sup) as sup
    FROM
    (
        --this subquery is key for getting things in supplier order, by descending id
        SELECT *
        FROM `sample_table`
        ORDER BY supplier, ID DESC
     ) reverse_order_by_id
    INNER JOIN
    (
        -- initialize the variables used to their first ever values
        SELECT @cumulative_quantity := 0, @sup := 0, @reached_five := 0
    ) only_here_to_initialize_variables
) t_alias
where reached_five <= 1 -- only get things up through the time we first get to 5 or above.
```

Comment: Also, note that you can remove the outermost select to see what the SELECT with all the variables is actively doing.  It helps to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has no concept of 'what row number am I up to', so this can only be implemented using something called a cursor. Writing code with cursors is something like writing code with for loops in other languages.

An example of how to use cursors is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Hi Patashu, thank you for the reply. Sorry if my question was confusing. However, I do not need to get the row number. Just all contents of the entire row. just as in a typical query. IE : I need to run the query to "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE supplier=1 until the total qty >= 5 order by DESC. something like that. Just dont know how to get all records until total is >= 5. sorry if i made it more confusing

Comment: This table has a sequential key (it's an auto-incrementing integer but could just as easily have been a compound key formed on a date/timestamp and the supplier id), so we are not restricted to cursors in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough demo about cursor, may be it's helpful.

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    ID       INT IDENTITY,
    Supplier INT,
    QTY      INT
);


TRUNCATE TABLE #t;

INSERT  INTO #t (Supplier, QTY)
VALUES         (1, 2),
(1, 2),
(2, 5),
(3, 2),
(1, 3);

DECLARE @sum AS INT;

DECLARE @qty AS INT;

DECLARE @totalRows AS INT;

DECLARE curSelectQTY CURSOR
    FOR SELECT   QTY
        FROM     #t
        ORDER BY QTY DESC;

OPEN curSelectQTY;

SET @sum = 0;

SET @totalRows = 0;

FETCH NEXT FROM curSelectQTY INTO @qty;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sum = @sum + @qty;
        SET @totalRows = @totalRows + 1;
        IF @sum >= 5
            BREAK;
    END

SELECT   TOP (@totalRows) *
FROM     #t
ORDER BY QTY DESC;

CLOSE curSelectQTY;

DEALLOCATE curSelectQTY;
```

Comment: is above stored procedure retrieve only those records above or equal to 5?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM supplier_stock x 
  JOIN supplier_stock y  
    ON y.supplier = x.supplier 
   AND y.id >= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY supplier
     , id 
HAVING SUM(y.qty) <=5;
```

Comment: This ALMOST works.  The goal is to get the qty >= 5.