# How to SUM a column until certain value from database?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two simple table.

```
TABLE_1
ID     CATEGORY     ACT_ID        COUNT
 1           C1      ACT01           XXX 
 2           C2      ACT03           XXX 
 3           C3      ACT05           XXX 

TABLE_2
CATEGORY     ACT_ID     VALUE
      C1      ACT01         1
      C1      ACT02         2
      C1      ACT03         1
      C1      ACT04         5
      C1      ACT05         1
      C2      ACT01         2      
      C2      ACT02         5   
      C2      ACT03         1   
      C2      ACT04         1   
      C2      ACT05         4   
      C3      ACT01         2
      C3      ACT02         2
      C3      ACT03         4
      C3      ACT04         5
      C3      ACT05         7
```

So, I'd like to `SUM` the `VALUE` from `TABLE_2` based on `ACT_ID`. The `SUM` should stop if it reach the exist `ACT_ID` in `TABLE_1`. The final output should be:

```
    TABLE_1
ID     CATEGORY     ACT_ID        COUNT
 1           C1      ACT01             1 
 2           C2      ACT03             8 
 3           C3      ACT05            20
```

I'm using MySQL

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I see some example here but it different from my question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450660/select-rows-until-a-total-amount-is-met-in-a-column-mysql

Comment: Well, when you're ready...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TABLE_1.ID,TABLE_1.CATEGORY, TABLE_1.ACT_ID, SUM(TABLE_2.VALUE) COUNT  FROM  TABLE_1
JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_2.ACT_ID = TABLE_1.ACT_ID
GROUP BY TABLE_2.ACT_ID
```