# How to SUM by each one iteration with if condition - using mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to sum each value by iteration and when the condition matches they trigger the date value and total sum.

```
+------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|       id   | EMAIL                            | created    | Amt    |
+------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|         61 | abc@gmail.com                    | 1514909390 |  57.00 |
|         25 | xyz@gmail.com                    | 1515534837 | 360.00 |
|         36 | zccc@abv.com                     | 1515645391 | 240.00 |
|         22 | vv@aa.com                        | 1516419622 | 320.40 |
|         48 | aa@xyz.com                       | 1516706121 | 240.00 |
+------------+----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

**Expected Output:**

if(Amt=>600) then I need the (Created (1515645391)) the third row created date.

Above is sample data of result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look in here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450660/select-rows-until-a-total-amount-is-met-in-a-column-mysql

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: Hi @AbhishekGinani please have a look the expected output. when the condition matches, I want the current row date.

Comment: I 've asked you to add the expected output, not the cases.Add output in a table format similar to sample data you provided.